# Catch the rows of data causing batchUpdateException

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

Code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
 
public class BatchInsertErrorHandlingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties myProp = new Properties();
        myProp.put("user", "ExampleUser");
        myProp.put("password", "password123");
        Connection conn;
        
        // establish connection and make a table for the data.
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:vertica://VerticaHost:5433/ExampleDB",
                            myProp);
            
            
            // Disable auto commit
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
       
            // Create a statement
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // Drop table and recreate.
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers CASCADE");
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE customers (CustID int, Last_Name"
                            + " char(50), First_Name char(50),Email char(50), "
                            + "Phone_Number char(12))");
            
            // Some dummy data to insert. The one row won't insert because
            // the phone number is too long for the phone column.
            String[] firstNames = new String[] { "Anna", "Bill", "Cindy",
                            "Don", "Eric" };
            String[] lastNames = new String[] { "Allen", "Brown", "Chu",
                            "Dodd", "Estavez" };
            String[] emails = new String[] { "aang@example.com",
                            "b.brown@example.com", "cindy@example.com",
                            "d.d@example.com", "e.estavez@example.com" };
            String[] phoneNumbers = new String[] { "123-456-789",
                            "555-444-3333", "555-867-53093453453",
                            "555-555-1212", "781-555-0000" };
            
            // Create the prepared statement
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO customers (CustID, Last_Name, " + 
                            "First_Name, Email, Phone_Number)" +
                            " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            
            // Add rows to a batch in a loop. Each iteration adds a
            // new row.
            for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {
                // Add each parameter to the row.
                pstmt.setInt(1, i + 1);
                pstmt.setString(2, lastNames[i]);
                pstmt.setString(3, firstNames[i]);
                pstmt.setString(4, emails[i]);
                pstmt.setString(5, phoneNumbers[i]);
                // Add row to the batch.
                pstmt.addBatch();
            }
            
            // Integer array to hold the results of inserting
            // the batch. Will contain an entry for each row,
            // indicating success or failure.
            int[] batchResults = null;
            
            try {
                // Batch is ready, execute it to insert the data
                batchResults = pstmt.executeBatch();
            } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
                // We expect an exception here, since one of the
                // inserted phone numbers is too wide for its column. All of the
                // rest of the rows will be inserted.
                System.out.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
                
                // Batch results isn't set due to exception, but you
                // can get it from the exception object.
                //
                // In your own code, you shouldn't assume the a batch
                // exception occurred, since exceptions can be thrown
                // by the server for a variety of reasons.
                batchResults = e.getUpdateCounts();
            }
            // You should also be prepared to catch SQLExceptions in your own
            // application code, to handle dropped connections and other general
            // problems.
            
            // Commit the transaction
            conn.commit();
            
            
            // Print the array holding the results of the batch insertions.
            System.out.println("Return value from inserting batch: "
                            + Arrays.toString(batchResults));
            // Print the resulting table.
            ResultSet rs = null;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT CustID, First_Name, "
                            + "Last_Name FROM customers ORDER BY CustID");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " - "
                                + rs.getString(2).trim() + " "
                                + rs.getString(3).trim());
            }
            
            // Cleanup
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[ OUTPUT ]

Error message:

> [Vertica]VJDBC One or more rows were rejected by the server.Return
> value from inserting batch: [1, 1, -3, 1, 1] 1 - Anna Allen 2 - Bill
> Brown 4 - Don Dodd 5 - Eric Estavez

I can catch the exception easily with this, but I want to catch the data which was rejected. Is there any way to retrieve that data?

O want to print the data which gives out -3 value.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC API offers no such facility. If you want to track this, you'll need to keep track of which sets of values you added to the batch yourself, and then use the index in the array returned by `BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts()` to find out what the actually values were (index 0 is the first set of values added to the batch, index 1 is the second set of vales, and so on).